# How can I edit the 'Posts' page in wordrpess editor?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to edit the "POSTS" page(where all the posts are listed and paginated) in wordpress editor , but not able to do so through various options available

I have tried to do some editing through the theme file editor and even the parent theme but i have not been successful as of now, can you suggest me how can edit it? all i want to edit it?

Comment: This is archive page and you cant edit it trough editor. You have to edit archive.php. Some page builders allow editing archives but not the default one.

Comment: @Snuffy thanks , but where can i find the archive.php page? in parent theme or child theme?

Comment: It should be in your parent theme. Use child theme to modify it so you wont lose any changes when you update the parent theme. If its missing then create one in your child theme. Learn more about template structure here - https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/